# How to find the frequency of second histogram based on quantile of first

Tags: r, random, quantile

I have two sets of data.  In the first set I can calculate the 25th percentile and output the x value.  I would then like to take that x value to a second data set and determine the frequency and percentile at the same point.

As an example, here is some code based on a random variate (the actual data is not random)

```
data1 = rnorm(10000, mean=8, sd=1.3)
data2 = rnorm(10000, mean=4, sd=1.0)

#plot data1 histogram with 40 bins
hist(data1, breaks=40, col="red", xlim=c(2,14), ylim=c(0,800),
     main="Gaussian deviates :  mean=8, sigma=1.3", col.main="blue")
segments(quantile(data1,0.25), 0, quantile(data1,0.25), 600, col="green", lwd=4, lty=1)

#plot data2 histogram with 40 bins
hist(data2, breaks=40, col="red", xlim=c(2,14), ylim=c(0,900),
     main="Gaussian deviates :  mean=4, sigma=1.0", col.main="blue")
print(quantile(data1,0.25))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ecdf()` function on the second set of data to create the empirical cumulative distribution function. You can then input values and see where they fall within the empirical distribution. So in this case, The 25th percentile of `data1` is the `99.93` percentile of `data2`. I'm not quite sure what "the frequency" is referring to.

```
set.seed(100)
data1 = rnorm(10000, mean=8, sd=1.3)
data2 = rnorm(10000, mean=4, sd=1.0)

#plot data1 histogram with 40 bins
hist(data1, breaks=40, col="red", xlim=c(2,14), ylim=c(0,800),
     main="Gaussian deviates :  mean=8, sigma=1.3", col.main="blue")
segments(quantile(data1,0.25), 0, quantile(data1,0.25), 600, col="green", lwd=4, lty=1)



q1 <- quantile(data1, 0.25)
#plot data2 histogram with 40 bins
hist(data2, breaks=40, col="red", xlim=c(2,14), ylim=c(0,900),
     main="Gaussian deviates :  mean=4, sigma=1.0", col.main="blue")


print(quantile(data1,0.25))
#>      25% 
#> 7.133474
ecdf(data2)(q1)
#> [1] 0.9993
```

Comment: Thanks.  It would be the y-value of the frequency distribution.

Comment: Do you mean the y-value at the bin which contains 7.133474? The number of observations which occur before 7.133474?

Comment: I believe the OP wants the density of the found percentile point expressed as frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's find the `25th` percentile from the first distribution:

```
q25 <- quantile(data1,0.25)
```

Secondly, let's create an empirical cumulative distribution function for the second data set:

```
dist2 <- ecdf(data2)
```

Thirdly, let's create an approximate distribution function for the second data set:

```
df <- approxfun(density(data2))
```

So, the percentile for the second distribution is:

```
dist2.percentile <- dist2(q25)

> dist2.percentile
[1] 0.9986
```

Density on `dist2.percentile` is:

```
dist2.density <- df(q25)
> dist2.density
[1] 0.003380966
```

with approximate frequancy of:

```
dist2.frequency <- dist2.density * 10000
> dist2.frequency
[1] 33.80966
```

Finally, check that the area under the approximate density function is accurate enough, *i.e.* approximately equals to 1.

```
> sum(df(quantile(dist2)[1]:quantile(dist2)[5]))
[1] 1.014089
```